# Date format in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

A simple syntactical question may be

While trying to display the date in my custom format, i am using

```
date '+DATE %m-%y%nTIME %H:%M:%S'
```

What is the purpose of '+' symbol before specifying Date format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` tells date that you want it to be in that format. From the man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
   date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
   date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

Otherwise, date thinks you are trying to send it a date string (`[MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]`), not a format string.

Comment: what do you mean by the date string and what is the purpose of it ?

Comment: @nlingutla the date string (e.g. `08111847` for Aug 11th, 18:47) is used to set the system date/time.